# Creating NSObject not sure where to download

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, nsobject

I am a little confused on the proper way to implement an NSObject model. I am creating a `Book` class that will story some data (NSString, UIImage, etc.) but I am storing the data on a server. Should I create a method for `Book` like `-(void)loadDataFromServerWithID:(NSString *)bookID` then when I create a `Book` like this:

```
Book *book = [Book alloc] init];
[book loadDataFromServerWithID:@"1234"];
```

and within the loadDataFromServer method download the JSON data and assign the instance variables to the object?

I've been thinking of many ways I can do this but I'm not really sure anyway is efficient/smart way to do it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to have only 1 class responsible for talking to the server, then have a method in the class called something like `bookFromServerWithID:` that returns a new book object ready to go. Other variations include some form of callback to avoid blocking the main thread.

To do asynchronous loading, you would create a method similar to [`[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest%3aqueue%3acompletionHandler%3a) and would probably call the mentioned method somewhere in your loader. On the callback, you would parse the data from the connection and give the callback to your method the `Book` object.

If you haven't worked with queues before, the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091) is a helpful (if slightly long and in-depth) read.

Comment: can you point me in the right direction for doing a callback to avoid blocking the main thread?

Comment: @mkral updated with some more information about asynchronous loading.

Answer (score 1):

How do you handle the retrieval of data from the server? You should always make asynchronous calls in your app in order not to block the UI. I encourage you to try [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). If your server sends back JSON, it'll be directly converted into an NSDictionary.

I like to have an init method in my models that looks like this :

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
        self.nbOfPages = [dictionary objectForKey:@"nbOfPages"];
        // etc.
    }

    return self;
}
```

Where the parameter is the dictionary you get once the JSON has been parsed.

Ben Scheirman [made a screencast](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/6-afnetworking) about AFNetworking where he explains exactly how to accomplish this, you should check it out

Comment: I've just started using AFNetworking and really love it. In the success block would you call this initWithDictionary?

Comment: Exactly, that's where you're supposed to call it. If your call gets you back the JSON for one book, the response object in your success block should be the dictionary you need to instantiate your Book object with the method I've described.